# Parsing a fixed number of XML children ordered by last using PHP

Tags: php, xml, filter

I am attempting to return a fixed number of XML nodes ordered by last so that I can display a "Recently added" filter.  I am not storing the date. How do I filter on the last 10 nodes using PHP?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trackList>
  <track>
    <title>Lost in the Star</title>
    <creator>Toshiki Hayashi</creator>
    <cover>images/thinlines.jpg</cover>
    <location>mp3/toshiki hayashi - lost in the star.mp3</location>
    <genre>hip-hop</genre>
    <playlist>2</playlist>
  </track>
  <track>
    <title>Black Orpheusr</title>
    <creator>Ouska</creator>
    <cover>images/ouska.jpg</cover>
    <location>mp3/ouska - Black Orpheus.mp3</location>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <playlist>2</playlist>
  </track>
  <track>
    <title>Soul Below</title>
    <creator>Ljones</creator>
    <cover>images/Ljones.jpg</cover>
    <location>mp3/Ljones - Soul Below.mp3</location>
    <genre>hip-hop</genre>
    <playlist>2</playlist>
  </track>
</trackList>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('playlist100.xml', NULL, TRUE);

foreach($xml->xpath('//track[playlist="1"]') as $child)
    {
    echo '<div class="song"><a href="' . $child->location . '">';
    echo '<img src="' . $child->cover . '" alt="cover" />';
    echo '<span class="artist">' . $child->creator . '</span>';
    echo '<span class="songTitle">' . $child->title . '</span></a></div>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: please provide some code how you have tried till now.

Comment: The XML

<trackList>
  <track>
    <title>Soul Below</title>
    <creator>Ljones</creator>
    <cover>images/Ljones.jpg</cover>
    <location>mp3/Ljones - Soul Below.mp3</location>
    <genre>hip-hop</genre>
    <playlist>2</playlist>
  </track>
  <track>
    <title>Por Tus Errores</title>
    <creator>Dj Neber</creator>
    <cover>images/djNeber.jpg</cover>
    <location>mp3/Dj Neber - Por Tus Errores.mp3</location>
    <genre>latin</genre>
    <playlist>2</playlist>
  </track>
</trackList>

Comment: where are you storing the data?

Comment: $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('playlist100.xml', NULL, TRUE);

Comment: <?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('playlist100.xml', NULL, TRUE);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//track[playlist="1"]') as $child)
 {
 echo '<div class="song"><a href="' . $child->location . '">';
 echo '<img src="' . $child->cover . '" alt="cover" />';
 echo '<span class="artist">' . $child->creator . '</span>';
 echo '<span class="songTitle">' . $child->title . '</span></a></div>';
 }
?>

Comment: Now you are getting 100? instead you want to get 10?

Comment: Sort of...
I want to get the last 10 added to the XML file.

Comment: can you share the XML file?

Comment: XML structure posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an XSLT solution where you transform the original file to select only the last 10 nodes by using the `count()` function. Since XSLT is a well-formed XML file, you can read it in like any other XML file, use it to transform original, and process output with SimpleXML.

**XSLT** *(save externally as .xsl or embed in PHP as string)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="trackList">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(track) - 9"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="track[position() &gt;= $count]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="track">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->load('playlist100.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($dom);

// PROCESS NEW XML STRING
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($newXml);

foreach($xpath = $xml->xpath('//track') as $child)
    {
    echo '<div class="song"><a href="' . $child->location . '">';
    echo '<img src="' . $child->cover . '" alt="cover" />';
    echo '<span class="artist">' . $child->creator . '</span>';
    echo '<span class="songTitle">' . $child->title . '</span></a></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait!  
Trying unsuccessfully to also shuffle the tracks before writing them out.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by shuffle? XSLT can order nodes as well.

Comment: PHP has the ability to shuffle an array.  I want to shuffle, or randomize the order.

Comment: What array? Your post only involves an XML file. And if you randomize, how do you decide last 10 nodes?

Comment: I'm trying to randomize the order of the 10 nodes (actually displaying 100) to mix them up every time.

Comment: Forgive me but that might be another question. Did this answer your posted need of *Parsing a fixed number of XML children ordered by last using PHP*?

Comment: Great! Please accept to confirm resolution and post the interested question on randomized elements. Maybe we'll meet again!